# Electric Flux in a uniform Electric field

Tags: electrostatics

If you have a symmetric object like a cylinder in a uniform electric field (either parallel or perpendicular to axis), you can easily see flux would be zero due to symmetry.

Suppose now you put a non symmetric object like a hemisphere in a unform electric field  (field is paralle to axis), flux should still be zero.? whatever line of force enter the hemishere has to somehow leave the hemisphere so net should be zero. The actual answer for it is not zero it is π R squared E.

Comment: If by hemisphere you mean half of a sphere surface, with a boundary at the equator, then yes, you would get this answer. If your hemisphere does not haveh a Boundary at equator the total flux should be zero.

Comment: thx. not sure if understand the boundary nuance. Can you pls explain.? thx

Comment: The effective surface of a hemisphere  parallel to rotation axis is pi R squared. If your electric field penetrates it once you get your mentioned answer. The question is how the hemisphere  object is defined.

Comment: i have no idea what you're asking in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the two cases you bring up is that the flux is zero *through a closed surface* like a cylinder since what comes in must come out in a uniform field, adding up to no flux overall. The answer is different for a surface that is not closed such as a sheet of paper or a hemisphere, since what goes through the surface never reemerges through "the other side," adding up to nonzero flux.

Let the radius of the hemisphere be $R$, and assume that it sits upon the top-half of the $x,y$-plane in $3D$ space. Suppose that the uniform field $\vec E$ points upwards in the $z$-direction. Then, the flux through the hemisphere is exactly the same as the flux through the "opening" of the hemisphere, that is the disk of radius $R$ sitting in the $x,y$-plane, since what comes in through that disk must go through the hemisphere. Hence the flux through the hemisphere $\phi_H$ is the same as the flux through the disk $\phi_D$ of area $A$, which is
$$
\phi_D = \vec E\cdot \vec A = E\cdot(\pi R^2).
$$
In general, to determine the flux $\phi$ through a surface $S$ with a nonuniform field, we employ a so-called *vector surface integral*:
$$
\phi = \iint_S \vec E\cdot d\vec S.
$$
It's something to keep in mind.

Just something else to add to the already complete discussion, note that the flux through the *closed surface* that is the disk plus the hemisphere is *zero*. This is always true for closed surfaces in uniform fields. In addition, what comes in through one surface exits through the other. In the case of the *closed surface* that is the disk plus the hemisphere, the flux $\phi$ is
$$
0 = \phi = \phi_D + \phi_H
$$
so $\phi_D = -\phi_H$, which makes sense since the flux comes "in" through the disk, and leaves, or "enters negatively" (it's a ridiculous way of putting it, I'm aware) through the hemisphere. This is because $\phi_H$ is actually negative, indicating that there is a net flux out of the surface through the hemisphere. So the positive flux $\phi_D$ through the disk is the same as the negative of the negative flux $\phi_H$ through the hemisphere. In other words,

*what comes in must come out.*

Answer (score 0):

The flux will be zero if the hemisphere is closed or gas a solid base. In that case flux from the curved surface will cancel the flux from the flat surface. 
But if the hemisphere is open (like a bowl) then there is only one surface so flux would be the one you received